# Java verificar duas tabelas dentro do SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql

Tenho um banco de dados que possui duas tabelas, sendo elas `EstoqueDBQ` e `FilaDBQ`, preciso criar a seguinte lógica.

Se o valor existe na tabela **FilaDBQ** e no E**stoqueDBQ**, esse valor deve ser excluído da FilaDBQ, pensei em usar o código abaixo, mais estou tendo problema para adaptação.

```
    String sql = "SELECT UM FROM FilaDBQ [.....]";
    Cursor data = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     Se é verdade, apagar o valor na tabela FilaDBQ
    } else {
   Se não, nada acontece.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prezados consegui solucionar realizando o filtro diretamente na consulta,
segue a query abaixo.

```
SELECT UM FROM FILADBQ WHERE NOT IN (SELECT UM FROM ESTOQUEDBQ)
```

Essa condição apenas faz o filtro ou seja o dado não é apagado do banco de dados, mais para a minha aplicação essa função é perfeitamente aceitável!

Caso alguem precise deletar o registro é só usar a query abaixo:

```
   DELETE FROM FILADBQ WHERE IN (SELECT UM FROM ESTOQUEDBQ)
```

Forte abraço!